# Connecting to Guacamole Client without showing token in url

Tags: tomcat, client, guacamole

Currently, I am first getting the authToken from api/tokens end point. The changing the window location to https://{guacServer}/#client/{connectionId}?token={authToken}.

But now I want to pass the token as a header as in this  PR(https://github.com/apache/guacamole-client/pull/649).

I tried passing the token in header in XMLHttp request, but it gives 403 error for api/token.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Guacamole Authorization - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h3>Verification is in progress, kindly wait </h3>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getQueryVariable( variable )
            {
                let query = window.location.search.substring( 1 );
                let vars = query.split( "&" );
                for ( let i = 0; i < vars.length; i++ )
                {
                    let pair = vars[i].split( "=" );
                    if ( pair[0] == variable ) { return pair[1]; }
                }
                return ( false );
            }

            $( document ).ready( function ()
            {
                let guacServer = decodeURIComponent( getQueryVariable( "guacserver" ) );
                let connectionId = decodeURIComponent( getQueryVariable( "connectionId" ) );
                let connectionData = decodeURIComponent( getQueryVariable( "connectionData" ) );
                let settings = {
                    "url": guacServer + "/api/tokens",
                    "method": "POST",
                    "timeout": 0,
                    "headers": {
                        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                    },
                    "data": {
                        "data": connectionData
                    }
                };
                $.ajax( settings ).done( function ( authData )
                {
                    console.log( authData );
                    let authToken = authData.authToken;
                    //window.location.href = guacServer + '/#/client/' + connectionId + '?token=' + authToken; // this works
                    let url = guacServer + "/#/client/" + connectionId;
                    
                    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    req.open( 'GET', url );
                    req.setRequestHeader( 'Guacamole-Token', authToken )
                    req.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', "application/json" )
                    req.onload = function ()
                    {

                         document.open()
                         document.write( req.responseText )
                         window.location.href = url
                         document.close()
                     }
                     req.send();

                } ).fail( function ( data )
                {
                    console.log( "error data: " + data );
                    alert( "Failed to authorize. Either token is expired or connection parameter is corrupt" )
                } );

            } );
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```